# Javascript Trying to shuffle my deck of cards array, but can't understand how to pass the array in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a personal project/watching tutorials just to get have some fun making a game for school. Ultimately it's a war card game I played as a kid - highest number wins. I am trying to randomize my array of cards, I have 52 objects stored just the way I want, but now I ran into this road block.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            War Cards!
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="start"></div>
            <div id="message"></div>
            <div id="board">
                <div id="player1" class="players">
                    <div class="score"></div>
                    <div class="hand"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="player2">
                    <div class="score"></div>
                    <div class="hand"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="action">
                <button id="btnBattle" type="button" class="btn">
                    Fight!
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $('document').ready(function() {
                var suits = ["spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diams"];
                var cardFace = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
                var cards = [];
                var players = [[], []];
                var firstRun = true;
                var fightButton = document.querySelector("#btnBattle");

                fightButton.addEventListener('click', battle);

                function battle()
                {
                    if (firstRun)
                    {
                        firstRun = false;
                        buildCards();
                        shuffleArray();
                    }
                    console.log('Works');
                }


                function buildCards()
                {
                    cards = [];
                    for (s in suits)
                    {
                        var suitNew = suits[s][0].toUpperCase();
                        for(n in cardFace)
                        {
                            var card = {
                                suit:suits[s],
                                num:cardFace[n],
                                cardValue:parseInt(n) +2,
                                icon:suitNew
                            }
                            cards.push(card);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(cards);
                }

                function shuffleArray(array)
                {
                    for(var x = array.length -1; x > 0; x--)
                    {

                        var ii = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x + 1))
                        var temp = array[x];
                        console.log(temp)
                    }
                    return array;
                }










            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It is quite straightforward to implement.

Comment: Don't forget to declare variables `s` and `n` inside the `buildCards` function...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid adding everything to the global scope. Below, I return the cards from `buildCards()` and pass the cards into `shuffleArray()` (Which I copied from [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) as your original `shuffleArray` function did not actually move any elements around):

```js
var suits = ["spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diams"];
var cardFace = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
var players = [[], []];
var firstRun = true;

function battle()
{
    if (firstRun)
    {
        firstRun = false;
        var cards = buildCards();
        var randomized = shuffleArray(cards);
        console.log(randomized);
    }
    console.log('Works');
}


function buildCards()
{
    var cards = [];
    for (s in suits)
    {
        var suitNew = suits[s][0].toUpperCase();
        for(n in cardFace)
        {
            var card = {
                suit:suits[s],
                num:cardFace[n],
                cardValue:parseInt(n) +2,
                icon:suitNew
            }
            cards.push(card);
        }
    }
    
    return cards;
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

battle();
```

Comment: That works! I understand everything you did, up until the shuffleArray function, could you maybe explain that part a little more? I'm only 4 weeks into my javascript class haha

Comment: What do you want to know about the shuffleArray function? I just google searched for "fisher-yates shuffle javascript", found the first method, and copied it from here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Comment: @FrankerZ that particular shuffle function destroys its input array as part of its implementation logic.. Ouch !

Comment: @traktor53 Funny enough, I should have read the entire post. The better implementation was at the end (I've updated my post as a result)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a issue with the difference between formal and actual arguments when declaring and calling functions.

**Formal Arguments**

When you declare a function you give its arguments *formal* parameter names so you can refer to them inside the function. They don't have an actual value before the function is called. E.G. in  the shuffle function declaration

```
function shuffle( array) {....
```

`array` is a formal argument.

**Actual arguments**

Formal arguments are replaced by actual arguments when the function is called.

E.G. to shuffle the `cards` array you would call `shuffle` as

```
shuffle( cards);
```

supplying `cards` as the *actual* argument.

---

Note that the shuffle function looks to be implementing the Fisher-Yates algorithm but is missing two lines that swap array entries `x` and `ii`.

Here's a copy of a shuffle function with the missing lines:

```
function shuffle( a) { // fisher yates algorithm ;
    for( var i = a.length; --i;) {
        var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i+1));
        var temp = a[i]; // swap entries at i and j
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

You can change the formal parameter name `a`, and references to it in the function body, to `array` if you like.

Note that array elements are shuffled "in place" so there is no need to return the array parameter value since it hasn't changed.